# aiohttp websocket performance testing with locust

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, locust, aiohttp

I wrote websocket server using [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) python library.

Now I'm trying to test performance using [locust](http://locust.io/) and this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/yamionp/9112dd6e54694d594306), but locust can't open more than 2000 connections (websocket.create_connection() raises error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer).

I don't understand where's the problem. Is locust can't open so much connections or aiohttp can't handle so much connections(but it don't write any errors) or maybe ubuntu drops new connections(i set ulimit to 1000000, but cpu usage is almost 100%).

Comment: Did you set ulimit for both locust and aiohttp server?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov yes, i did.
Before i did it, both locust and aiohttp had been raising IOError: Too many open files

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using for testing the connection?